# How can I wrap content with different background?

Tags: html, css

I am new to learning web design ,
please take a look at > [this images](https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1/q71/577349_10151926356198174_832219630_n.jpg)

here I want to wrap a content in a 960px width ( red box )
but I want that every content / section is having a different background color ( just for example ) **but the background width is exceed the wrapper** , or maybe full width / 100%

how can I do this ?
thanks

EDIT :
just for example the site that doing something like this is IMAGESHACK the background color is full width of the screen but the content still wrap to main wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a container with the width of 960px:

```
<div class="lightGray">
    <div class="container" style="width:960px">Content</div>
</div>

<div class="medGray">
    <div class="container" style="width:960px">Content</div>
</div>

<div class="darkGray">
    <div class="container" style="width:960px">Content</div>
</div>
```

This will allow the colors to expand all the way across the screen, as well as expand as content expands. I would, of course, stray away from inline styling. Just make a class called container:

```
.container {width: 960px;}
```

Comment: thanks it works :) , cant believe i cant think as simple as this

Comment: Haha we have all been there :) Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the CSS property `overflow`.

Here is an example: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

And here is the summary: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Do you know about `div` ? They are very useful for this kind of things!

Comment: yes i'm using div for every content that has different background , but how can the background exceed the wrapper width ( 960px ) when it is inside the wrapper ? thanks

Comment: @user3181160 please provide a JSFiddle to test it !

Comment: I didn't see the problem in that JSFiddle. What is it?